# Find the total number of words in the file in python

Tags: python

I have a file contains 48 words but when I write the code to count the number of words in this file , the output result gives me only 42 words !. Here is my code:

```
with open('data_words.txt','r') as file:
    data=file.read()
    file.close()
    words=data.split(" ")

num_words=len(words)
print(num_words)
```

Comment: A sample of your file, please?

Comment: Are the words on multiple lines?

Comment: Are they really words or chars? Maybe the new lines are being counted?

Comment: are you sure there are 48 space-separated 'words'?

Comment: yes ,the words on multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.split(" ")` only splits words that are separated specifically by space. If they're separated by newline, they won't be split.

`data.split()` with no argument will split on any type of whitespace, so words that are separated by space or newline will be split.

Comment: Likely the problem. Please mention OP should not double `close` the file.